# Canvas doesn't draw/update properly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm making a graphing system with HTML canvas and it's mostly done but I'm having some trouble with one part. I've already figured out how to get graphing nodes to appear where the user wants, but when I use the same method on HTML elements I've added to the DOM with JavaScript it just wont work. I'm very sure the issue lies with the `newCoordsX.value` & `newCoordsY.value` because the system graphs the node on the screen in the bottom left corner, but the origin is on the top right, it shouldn't be in the bottom left without some sort of instructions to do so. It wont respond to any inputs it will only graph the node at the bottom left. I want it to be graphed based on the number the user enters. Here is some information on the variables you'll see in the program. `addN` is a button which will preform the event on click. `nodeAr` is an object which keeps track of the amount of clicks there have been on the button so it can stop the new inputs from showing up after 8 clicks. `chunk` is equal to 75. It is how many pixels are between each graph point. `node` is an array which each node is stored in. `update` draws the nodes on the graph. If you need any more information I'd be happy to show more code just let me know.

```
<div id="adda">
    <div id="add">Add another node</div>
</div>
```

```
addN.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let radius = 3;
    newCoordsX = document.createElement('input');
    newCoordsY = document.createElement('input');
    newCoordsX.placeholder = "X value";
    newCoordsY.placeholder = "Y value";
    newCoordsX.style.marginTop = margin + "px";
    newCoordsX.style.display = "block";
    newCoordsY.style.display = 'block';
    document.body.appendChild(newCoordsX);
    document.body.appendChild(newCoordsY);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    margin = 10;
    nodeAr.clicks +=1;

    let xPos = newCoordsX.value * chunk + 7;
    let yPos = 750 - newCoordsY.value * chunk - 4;

    if (nodeAr.clicks == 8){
        newCoordsX.style.display = 'none';
        newCoordsY.style.display = 'none';
        nodeAr.clicks--;
    };

    newCoordsX && newCoordsY.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
        if (ev.keyCode == 13){
            node.push(new Node(xPos, yPos, radius));
            for (let i=0; i < node.length; i++){
                node[i].update(node);
            };
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which illustrates and reproduces the problem when run.

Comment: It might be hard its part of a large function which uses a lot of HTML and it would be hard to wrap your head around how it works without a bulk of the program

Comment: @ggorlen the minimum amount of JavaScript i'd need to post for this to work is 121 lines of code

Comment: @ggorlen if you want to take it to a private chat i'd be glad to send you more than enough code to help me fix the issue

Comment: Simplifying the code down to show a minimal example is part of the process of asking an answerable question, so I'd recommend breaking it down to a simpler program and posting that.

Comment: I think ill just pursue it myself, I already know where to look for the problem.

Comment: And as I suspected I already solved it @ggorlen

Comment: @ggorlen You've been helpful throughout this post, would it be okay if I took down the question since I didn't get any answers to my solution, but you provided some helpful information for asking questions in the future

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Sure, take it down. Generally, by stripping down the problem to a minimal example, the solution becomes apparent (and if it still isn't, it's probably a great question to bring here). Note, you can also self-answer your own question, but if the question isn't well-formed in the first place, it probably won't be helpful to future visitors and is a better candidate for deletion.

Comment: We are still missing an [MCVE], but a few things that go wrong already: `newCoordsX && newCoordsY.addEventListener` won't do what you expected it will do. If you want to attach an event listener on both, then you need to call both methods: `newCoordsX.addEventListener(... ; newCoordsY.addEventListener(...`. Also, at the time you define `xPos` and `yPos`, your two <input> elements are still empty, so their `value` will be the empty string (`""`) which will then get coerced to `0`. So currently, there is no need at all for these inputs, hardcoding `0` in place of `node.value` will do the same.

Comment: @Kaiido I've already fixed most of the problems but `newCoordsX && newCoordsY.addEventListener` does exactly what I want. Im just having some trouble getting my program to draw the lines how I want I might need to make an entire function or something